# How to assign 3 rooms to 3 people with 1 coin randomly?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random

We are 3 friends; just checked into an airbnb flat with 3 rooms. And to make things truly random we decided to use 1 coin to assign each person a room. What's the best way to do this?
(Assuming coin flip is truly random.) (One way to define 'best' is minimum number of flips)

Answer (score 11):

Since there are six possible outcomes with equal probability, you'd b bettre off with a die, and unfortunately, the number of coin tosses cannot be bounded: With at most $k$ tosses, you can only define probabilities of the form $\frac m{2^k}$.

However, there is a nice(?) method for even more general probabilities: Start an infinite sequence of coin tosses (but don't worry, we will almost surely stop after just a few tosses) and interpret the outcomes as infinite binary number. So e.g. $HHTHHTHHHHTTTTTTHTTH\ldots$ becomes the binary number $.00100100001111110110\ldots$. Already with these 20 tosses, it is clear that our number is approximately $0.1415926\ldots$ in decimal. Now we assign the intervals $[0,\frac16)$, $[\frac16,\frac13)$, $[\frac13,\frac12)$, $[\frac12,\frac23)$, $[\frac23,\frac56)$, $[\frac56,1]$ so that each interval has length $\frac16$ (or whatever probabilty we want); also, it typically does not really matter if we assign the boundary points to the lower or upper interval. As $\frac16$ is $.0010101\ldots$ in binary, it is clear that our generated random number is $\in[0,\frac16)$ and hence we take the first of the six possible outcomes. Actually, we did way too much for the sake of insight into the example: Already after five tosses $HHTHH$, it is clear that our number will end up $\in[0,\frac16)$, hence we could have stopped there (but not earlier).

Comment: +1 for the first sentence. Step 1: Raid the Airbnb for a games cupboard that may contain a die.

Comment: I _vaguely_ remember reading some comment somewhere, saying that your binary-representation method requires the least expected number of coin flips.  (And certainly less than the $8/3$ in the other answer).  Do you have any insight into this issue, or maybe I mis-remembered?

Comment: @antkam: Asymptotically, as the number of choices tends to infinity, this method is indeed optimal. (It's basically a special case of [arithmetic decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding).) For just six equally likely choices, though, I believe it takes on average $4$ coin tosses, which is more than the $3+\tfrac23$ tosses needed with rejection sampling. (Specifically, toss two coins and reject one of the 4 outcomes to choose who gets picked first, then one more coin to decide who's next; QC_QAOA's answer currently leaves out that last coin toss.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - thank you very much for your comments and esp. the reference to arithmetic coding.  so what i remembered was the asymptotic result, not a $\forall n$ kind of result.  that makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

Each of you pick one of the following

$$HH,HT,TH,TT$$

Flip a coin twice and whoevers sequence is flipped gets their choice of room. If none of the sequences you picked are flipped ($25\%$ chance), then flip again. Next, go down the line above and whoevers sequence is next gets to pick their room next. For example, suppose I picked $TH$ while my friend picked $HT$. We flip a coin twice and it outputs $HT$. Then they would pick first, and I would pick second. If $TT$ is outputted then loop around to $HH$. Obviously, the third person gets the last room. The expected number of coin flips is

$$2\left(1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{64}+\cdots\right)=2\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^i}=2\frac{4}{3}=\frac{8}{3}=2.\overline{6}$$

Comment: The four pairs also have to be picked in some order. If you are the last to pick and the others have picked say $HH$ and $HT$, is there any strategic advantage to picking $TH$ vs. $TT$? (Of course one could eliminate any possible effect by replacing the "go down the line" step with another coin toss, but I'm curious if the proposed method works as-is.)

Comment: Well, that you arrange yourselves in some circular order: $A\to B\to C\to A\to B\to \cdots $ and then flip a coin in pairs of two untill you get either $A,B,$ or $C$. Then just continue down the line. The reason I suggested this instead of another coin toss is that it lowers the expected number of coin tosses, but you could always flip another coin to decide between the last two people.

Comment: A slight aside: serious random-number-generator software also uses this reattempt-based approach, where there's no hard upper bound on the number of re-attempts. I was surprised when I learnt there was no more elegant solution (at least assuming we insist on no bias at all). Here's OpenJDK doing it, the only difference being that it uses any 'invalid' values for additional entropy, rather than discarding them outright: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/eb1eadb69f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.java#L252

Comment: The question doesn't state anything about people getting to pick their room, but being assigned randomly. Does this change anything, assuming the goal is that each person has the same probability of being assigned to any room?

Comment: @anjama: It does change things, but generally for the better in practice: for example, if each person just happens to prefer a different room, then this procedure will always let all of them get their preferred room, whereas purely random assignment would only do that 1/6 of the time. On the other hand, if all of the people have the same room preferences, then this procedure _is_ equivalent to random assignment.

Comment: … For intermediate scenarios, where the preferences partially overlap, you quickly start getting deep into [social choice theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_choice_theory). But in general, allowing _some_ choice is still always better (in the sense of being more likely to give each person a room higher on their preference list) than just pure random assignment with no regard to individual preferences. And in any case this procedure is still "fair" in the sense that it treats all participants equally, with no _a priori_ bias.

Comment: BTW, I just noticed that this method, as written, does _not_ yield all possible orders. For example, if I choose HT and you choose TH (and our friend chooses TT or HH), then there's no outcome where you would get the first pick and I would get the second. To fix that, you'd need one more coin flip after the first pick to decide who goes second, bringing your expected number of coin flips up to $3.\overline6$.

Comment: Yes, that is true. The way I wrote does produce a random chance that you get first, second or third choice but doesn't allow for any permutation among the friends. Of course, if that is a big deal than you can always flip another time like you said.